# TThreadedStringList in delphi xe2

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

I am making heavy computations so i need to use a TStringList in a separate thread. Does XE2 has a special class defined for this because i thought it had if not what are my options.

Comment: Nothing built in to the best of my knowledge. What exactly is your requirement? Do you need to read from one thread at the same time as another other thread is writing? If so then you need locks.

Comment: Please provide more details.  Creating and using a TStringList in any thread is just fine, so there must be more to it.  Presumably, you are considering accessing one TStringList instance from more than one thread?

Comment: if XE2 still has it (I use Delphi 7) take a look at TThreadList. It wraps a TList but it would be easy to copy and make one for a TStringList.

Comment: I don't want the main application to freeze when some large ammount of data is added

Comment: @opc0de Do you need to have multiple threads accessing the list simulataneously?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no i don't need that , but i have manny strings and i think the Add method is executed in the main VCL thread or i am wrong ?

Comment: No, the Add method for `TStringList` is executed in the calling thread. It sounds like you have nothing to do at all. Just use a `TStringList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy ships with Delphi and has its own `TIdThreadSafeStringList` class available in the `IdThreadSafe.pas` unit.  It also has several other `TIdThreadSafe...` classes available for `Integer`, `Cardinal`, `Int64`, `String`, `TDateTime`, and `Double`.

Comment: But in this case there is no need for this

Comment: Though i will use @DavidHeffernan advice it's good to know that such classes exist for future development